# javascript difference in linking to new object with prototype vs none

Tags: javascript

I am looking at proto-chaining in javascript and I am confused about this below.

```
var Animal = function(name){this.name = name}
Animal.prototype.eats = function(){
      return this.name + " is eating."
}

var Cho = function(name){ this.name = name;}
Cho.prototype = new Animal();
```

I understand above code and what it's doing.
However, my question is, why can't I simply do below?

```
var Cho = new Animal();
```

Is this so that we can override this.name?

Comment: Need to clarify, I meant instead of writing last 2 lines in my original code, can I replace them w/ var Cho = new Animal(); and mean exactly the same as my original code given the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Cho = function(name){ this.name = name;}
Cho.prototype = new Animal();

// vs

var Cho = new Animal();
```

Both do totally different things. In the first code, `Cho` is a constructor "subclassing" from the `Animal` constructor. It's the same concept in classical OOP where one class extends from another class. The second code, `Cho` is an *instance* of `Animal`. If I remember my OOP analogies correctly, a class (a constructor in the case of JS) is a blueprint while an instance is the actual thing based on that blueprint.

I think what you mean is why can't we just create an instance of `Cho` directly from the `Animal` constructor instead of creating a `Cho` constructor that subclasses `Animal` and instance off of that.

```
var myCho = new Cho();
// vs
var myCho = new Animal();
```

Actually you can. Inheritance is an "is a" relationship. An instance of `Cho` *is an* instance of `Animal`. You can actually just use the `Animal` constructor to create `myCho` if `Cho` doesn't actually provide much change (like your sample code in this case, which introduces nothing new to `Cho`).

Comment: Thank you everyone's answer. I check this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Animal = function(name){this.name = name}
Animal.prototype.eats = function(){
      return this.name + " is eating."
}

var Cho = function(name){ this.name = name;}
Cho.prototype = new Animal();
```

What we are doing here is setting `Cho` prototype to an instance of `Animal`, so that `Cho` inherits all of `Animal's` properties.

```
var Animal = function(name){this.name = name}
Animal.prototype.eats = function(){
      return this.name + " is eating."
}

var Cho = function(name){ this.name = name;}
Cho.prototype = new Animal();
console.log(new Cho("Dog"));
```

The `Cho` object has its own name instance `property`, like we expected. When we look at the object’s prototype we see that it has also inherited Animal’s name instance property as well as the `eats` prototype property.

[image]

```
var Cho = new Animal();
```

With the above statement you are just assigning a `new instance of Animal` to `Cho`

Comment: But this is where my confusion is coming from. When you say new Animal, Cho is inheriting(well, through prototype chain) all Animal's property no? So it's almost samething except this.name = name. At that point, can I just say Cho.prototype.name = name ? So does those two line equal  now?  Does last 2 lines of my original code equal to var Cho = new Animal(); Cho.prototype.name = name ?

Comment: No, var Cho = new Animal(); Cho.prototype.name = name. they are different.. one cho variable has an animal instance where as in other you are modifying the Cho object to have a name property which would be available to all the instances of Cho...

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Cho.prototype = new Animal` you are subclassing so you can inherit methods and properties from the Animal. It is useful if you have two or more objects that share traits (properties || methods).

You can say 'Cho = new Animal` but it will mean you might have unnecessary duplication if another of your classes is also an animal.

It would be easier if the examples were Dog & Cat. A Dog is not a Cat, but they are both animals, they both eat, they both have 4 legs. but Dogs swim and Cats climb so you can put all the like methods on Animal, and the differences in their own Class that inherits animal.

```js
var Animal = function(name) {
  this.name = name
}
Animal.prototype.eats = function() {
  return this.name + " is eating."
}

var Cho = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Cho.prototype = new Animal();

Cho.prototype.choStuff = function() {
  return this.name + " does cho stuff";
};

var Foo = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Foo.prototype = new Animal();

Foo.prototype.fooStuff = function() {
  return this.name + " does foo stuff";
};

var cho = new Cho('cho'),
    foo = new Foo('foo');


console.assert(cho instanceof Cho, 'cho is a Cho');
console.assert(foo instanceof Foo, 'foo is a Foo');
console.assert(cho instanceof Animal, 'cho is an Animal');
console.assert(foo instanceof Animal, 'foo is an Animal');
console.assert(cho instanceof Foo, 'is cho a Foo' );
console.log( cho.eats() );
console.log( cho.choStuff() );
console.log( foo.eats() );
console.log( foo.fooStuff() );
console.assert('choStuff' in Animal.prototype, 'Animal has the choStuff method');
console.assert('choStuff' in Cho.prototype, 'Cho has the choStuff method');
console.assert('fooStuff' in Cho.prototype, 'Cho has the fooStuff method');

// now you can add to the prototype of Animal and have it propigate across to all subclasses.
console.assert( typeof cho.test === 'function', 'cho has a test method' );
console.assert( typeof foo.test === 'function', 'foo has a test method' );

Animal.prototype.test = function(){
  return true;
}

console.assert( typeof cho.test === 'function', 'cho has a test method' );
console.assert( typeof foo.test === 'function', 'foo has a test method' );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```